# Failed the private written test and I need an authorized instructor's statement, is there any way I can get that online?

Tags: faa-knowledge-test

I failed my Private written (I was being stupid and overconfident) but I got my endorsement online, I need an AUTHORIZED INSTRUCTOR'S STATEMENT to retake it and my original instructor is unavailable. Is there a way to get that online or do I have to find a new instructor to go over and sign off on it.

Comment: Hi ZKelly, welcome to Av.SE.  It looks like you have two separate accounts; please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for steps to merge them.  Also, please be aware that "resource location" (i.e. where can I obtain ___) is off-topic here, so you probably won't be able to get a list of online instruction providers who do that sort of follow-up (if such exist -- I'd be a little doubtful).  Although I think there are enough other aspects to your question that it's okay as it stands.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, don't be too hard on yourself for failing the Private Pilot written.  You're not the first person to underestimate the difficulty of the exam. You'll likely be exceptionally prepared for your next written test.

According to [FAR 61.49](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.49#p-61.49(a)) you need another endorsement as you noted in your question.

I'm assuming you took an FAA approved online course and received the initial endorsement via an online printed form validating that you have the proficiency to pass the knowledge (written) test.

Unless your initial online course provider (or another FAA approved provider) offers follow-up additional instruction and another endorsement via an online form, you would have to find an authorized instructor for this per FAR 61.49.

*(The regulation does not state that the endorsement to retake the written test must be from the original instructor).*

> [**61.49 Retesting after failure.**](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.49#p-61.49(a))
>
> > (a) An applicant for a **knowledge** or practical test who fails that test may reapply for the test only after the applicant has received:
> >
> > (1) The necessary training from an authorized instructor who has determined that the applicant is proficient to pass the test; and
> >
> > (2) **An endorsement from an authorized instructor who gave the applicant the additional training.**

*(emphasis is mine)*

It may also be helpful to review the [FAA's AIRMAN KNOWLEDGE TESTING MATRIX](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/2022-09/testing_matrix_2.pdf)
for additional information regarding Airman Knowledge Testing.  See page 13 of this document which addresses the Private Pilot Airplane knowledge (written) test (partial image shown below):

[image]

*(yellow highlight emphasis is mine)*